# QuotaExceededError with pouchdb

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb, cloudant

I have a big error with pouchDB communicating to my Cloudant database in a angular/ionic app.

Can you please help me figure out how to fix this ?

```
POST https://louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_bulk_get?revs=true&attachments=true&_nonce=1446478625328 400 (Bad Request)
pouchdb.min.js:8 Database has a global failure DOMError {}message: ""name: "QuotaExceededError"__proto__: DOMErrora.8.G.onsuccess.H.onabort @ pouchdb.min.js:8
ionic.bundle.min.js:139 o {status: 500, name: "abort", message: "unknown", error: true, reason: "QuotaExceededError"}error: truemessage: "unknown"name: "abort"reason: "QuotaExceededError"result: Objectdoc_write_failures: 1docs_read: 1docs_written: 0end_time: Mon Nov 02 2015 16:37:05 GMT+0100 (CET)errors: Array[1]last_seq: "3478-g1AAAAFJeJzLYWBgYMlgTmGQT0lKzi9KdUhJMtXLSs1LLUst0kvOyS9NScwr0ctLLckBKmRKZEiy____f1YGUxIDA3N6LlCMPdXM1MzEMo1oM5IcgGRSPcKYcLAxKZYGlslpSajGmOA2Jo8FSDI0ACmgSftRXJSSamFoYWmOapQ5IaMOQIwCuooZZFQhxHPmJkCURtigLAAxFGUZ"ok: falsestart_time: Mon Nov 02 2015 16:36:59 GMT+0100 (CET)status: "aborting"__proto__: Objectstatus: 500__proto__: r(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:139b.$get @ ionic.bundle.min.js:111(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:151a.$get.n.$eval @ ionic.bundle.min.js:165a.$get.n.$digest @ ionic.bundle.min.js:163(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:166e @ ionic.bundle.min.js:74(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:76
11ionic.bundle.min.js:139 Error: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.
    at Error (native)
    at a.9.n.openTransactionSafely (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:8:9233)
    at i.a.8.e._getLocal (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:8:2521)
    at i.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:7:6737)
    at i.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:10:28092)
    at i.a.90.t.exports (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:10:28931)
    at http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:9:28802
    at i.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:9:28722)
    at i.a.90.t.exports [as get] (http://localhost:8101/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js:10:28931)
    at i.angular.module.constant.service.$q.qify [as get] (http://localhost:8101/lib/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb.js:35:27)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:139b.$get @ ionic.bundle.min.js:111(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:151a.$get.n.$eval @ ionic.bundle.min.js:165a.$get.n.$digest @ ionic.bundle.min.js:163(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:166e @ ionic.bundle.min.js:74(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:76
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that the device has run out of space. Unfortunately this is an error thrown by IndexedDB itself when the device is too low on storage, so there's nothing you can do about it except to use less space. PouchDB's `compact()` can help; there's also the `transform-pouch` plugin if you want to just reduce the size of your documents.